# Changed to new Windows Phone but can't recover my backup

Tags: windows-10-mobile, backup

I just changed from Windows Phone.
I did a backup on the old one but on the new one, I had no WiFi, so I logged in to my Outlook account later. 
Now I don't know how to recover my backup (for the apps, texts,...)

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset the phone in order to restore.
When you switch on the phone after resetting, it will ask you for the Microsoft account that you used for the backup.